# VS 08 Express to Classic ASP

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, asp-classic

Here's the situation:

We have classic ASP running for our site.
We have VB6 DLLs, running inside the ASP as COM Objects.

I have moved over to Visual Studio 2008. I am trying to create DLLs that I can utilise in ASP the same way we would with VB6 (Server.CreateObject("")). Unfortunately, although registering is successful, I get a:
**"The call to Server.CreateObject failed while checking permissions. Access is denied to this object."** Error.

I have done plenty of research and found that you must register the VB.NET DLL with 'regasm' (which I did) you also need to tick the appropriate ("Make assembly COM-Visible") box.

However, through all my efforts, it seems I have run out of luck.
I did read something about having a class template called "COM Class" in order to create COM DLLs in VB.NET, but I do not have that option in the template choice.

So my question is, do I change to visual studio (non-express to obtain the COM class template and if so, would that definitely work?)

***OR***

Is there something that I am not doing correctly?

Please note moving to ASP.NET is not an option, nor programming in VB6.

Thanks!

*EDIT*

After about a full week of searching, I have found the answer, for anyone who finds this page: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9f84bdf7-aace-4a57-a3e4-3863a0efb647/how-to-create-comvisible-dll-that-i-can-use-from-vba-using-vs-express-2008-beta-2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9f84bdf7-aace-4a57-a3e4-3863a0efb647/how-to-create-comvisible-dll-that-i-can-use-from-vba-using-vs-express-2008-beta-2

> 1. Built the .dll, and targeted .NET Framework 3.5, making it COM visible.
> 2. Used the GAC utility that was installed with the Visual Studio 2008 Beta 2 (and hence >.NET Framework 3.5) - it was in C:\Program FIles\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\V.0A\bin - to place .the generated .dll into the GAC
> 3. Used the regsam.exe file I found in c:\ Windows\Microsoft.NET\framework\V2.0.50727 to >register the generated .dll.
> 4. Used the tlbexp.exe file I found in C:\Program FIles\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\V.0A\bin to >.export a .tlb file
> 5. In the VBA IDE, used Tools->References to browse to the .tlb file and select it as an >addtional reference.

The problem was that i was not doing step 2 or step 4.
I hope this helps someone in the future as it took me very long to solve.

Answer (score 0):

man you have to read about .net a lot.

you cannot just write a .net dll and then use this in classic asp. These are two completely different Technologies.

it has absolutely nothing to do with visual Studio. Visual Studio is just the development Environment and has absolutely nothing to do with your .net Framework or your web application. you cannot use visual Studio > version 6 for vb6 programming. so you cannot create vb6 dlls with visual Studio 2008n or 2010 or 2003 or 2005.

you can write .net dlls and use them in classic asp or any other com Aware Technology. but they are still .net dlls which require the .net Framework. they are just com visible.

that is a bit complicated but possible:
you classes and methods have to be "com visible" you achieve this by using the Attribute `[ComVisibleAttribute( true )]`
just before the declaration of your class and before every method you want to be com visible.
example:

```
[ComVisibleAttribute( true )]
public class Helper {
    public Helper() {
    }

    [ComVisibleAttribute( true )]
    public object parseDate( string strDate ) {
        return (object)DateTime.Parse( strDate ).ToString( "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss" );
    }
}
```

you have to use an emtpy constructor for your classes!

furthermore you have to check "Assemlby Com visible" in Project properties-> assemblyinformation
or open Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs and add These lines:

```
[assembly: ComVisible( true )]
[assembly: Guid( "e2e1670d-1f90-4948-98be-27cc820b4675" )]
```

after you have build your dll you then have to use the ragasm.exe to Register the .net dll in the registry. (normal .net dlls are note registeres n the registry by default.

you can do that like so:

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\regasm.exe path/and/Name/of/your.dll /codebase
```

you have to make sure that the path to your wanted .net Framework is correct.

after that you have to restart your iis and can then use the .net dll methids from classic asp.

please be Aware that you can only pass and return values of simple datatypes to your .net methods from/to clasic asp like string, int etc.

Comment: Okay, so, I have already tried those things (I tried them again, just in case) which I did say. I also am using VB not C. I think maybe you should re-read what I have said. I did, in no way, say that visual studio was anything but a development environment. I was asking if the template "COM Class" that comes with the normal visual studio and not the VS express was the reason i was not being able to  utilise the dll.